# Facilitate (XX) student-student interaction?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, sentence

I want to describe the advantage of small class.

> It facilitates [XX] teacher to student
>   interaction.

But I don't know what to fill in for [XX]. Can I say, closer and more effective?

> The advanatge of small class is that it facilitates closer and more
>   effective teacher to student interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with two small changes: "The advanatge of **a** small class is that it facilitates closer and more effective teacher **and** student interaction." Note that "interaction" means it is between the teacher and students, not just **from** the teacher **to** the student.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything in place of [XX]. The word *facilitate* already expresses what you describe. That is, "It facilitates teacher to student interaction" already means that it helps that interaction.

> **Facilitate** :  to make easier :  help bring about - [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facilitate)

Answer (score 0):

You could say that it facilitates ***[one-on-one](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one%E2%80%93on%E2%80%93one)*** interaction between the students and the teacher:

> involving a direct encounter between one person and another

[MW]